# App is getting launched, no lines are getting executed

Tags: ios, xctest

I am using **iOS -XCTest** framework, where I written two lines code for invoking the App and performing the type action.

The App is getting launched but none of the actions are get executed.

Can some one please help me on this?

---

I found a log as

> 2015-07-21 12:12:00:610 WordPress[3609:1707] Reachability - WordPress.com - WiFi: Y  WWAN: N  Carrier: (null)  Type: (null)
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00:611 WordPress[3609:1707] Reachability - WordPress.com - WiFi: Y  WWAN: N  Carrier: (null)  Type: (null)
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00:612 WordPress[3609:1707] Reachability - WordPress.com - WiFi: Y  WWAN: N  Carrier: (null)  Type: (null)
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00.625 WordPress[3609:42588] You are using Google+ iOS SDK version 1.5.0
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00.625 WordPress[3609:42588] Get the new version 1.7.1 at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00:681 WordPress[3609:8103]  cleanUnusedMediaFileFromTmpDir
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00:683 WordPress[3609:4c03] 0 media items to check for cleanup
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00.740 WordPress[3609:42524] Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file
>   2015-07-21 12:12:00:741 WordPress[3609:607] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions state:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help !!!

The issues with my approach, I was trying to automate the app which was build in old iOS. later I build my own app with latest iOS.Its working well and fine with XCTest.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to write those lines but record them:

- place your cursor in the test method
- hit the red record button at the bottom
- do the things in your app that you want to test

The recorded code is much more readable (and reproducable) when you provide accessibility names for your UI elements.